# Maximum number of statements within CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

```
WITH abidAccount AS
(
    SELECT 
        [ID], AzureBlobInsertDate = MAX(AzureBlobInsertDate)
    FROM 
        [dba].[CurAccounts] 
    GROUP BY 
        ID
),
recentAccount AS
(
    SELECT ca.*
    FROM [dba].[CurAccounts] ca
    JOIN abidAccount aa ON aa.[id] = ca.[ID]
                        AND aa.azureblobInsertDate = ca.azureBlobInsertDate
),
abidDevice AS
(
    SELECT deviceID, azureBlobInsertDate = MAX(azureBlobInsertDate)
    FROM [dba].[CurrentDevices]
    GROUP BY DeviceID
),
recentDevice AS
(
    SELECT cd.*
    FROM [RZRExploreLayer3].[CurrentDevices] cd
    JOIN abidDevice ad ON ad.DeviceID = cd.DeviceID
                       AND ad.azureBlobInsertDate = cd.azureblobinsertdate
)
SELECT  
    rd.deviceId,
    rd.[DeviceReturned],
    rd.accountNumber,
    rd.[DeviceFormat],
    rd.[DeviceLabel],
    MAX(ra.azureBlobInsertDate) AS AzureBlobInsertDate
FROM            
    recentAccount ra
JOIN   
    recentDevice rd ON ra.[id] = rd.accountNumber
WHERE  
    rd.deviceReturned NOT LIKE 'Null'
GROUP BY   
    rd.deviceId, rd.[DeviceReturned], rd.accountNumber,
    rd.[DeviceFormat], rd.[DeviceLabel]
    /* deviceID, rd.[DeviceReturned], rd.accountNumber, ra.azureBlobInsertDate */
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) > 1
```

How do I combine multiple CTE into one query?

My query is attempting to determine if there are duplicate records and if so only keep the max(AzureBlobInsertDate) record and remove other duplicates.  then combine all the results from the CurAccounts & Devices tables.

Any assistance you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the involved tables and some sample data for them as `INSERT INTO` statements. Also post the desired result with that sample data and do not forget to add the DBMS you're using to the tags.

Comment: I appreciate the need for this request.  but generally I am curious to how many queries can be contained within a CTE statement, and How do I join multiple CTE statements to get the final results.  Unfortunately due to propriertary data I am unable to post any versions of the data.

Comment: To be able to say something about any limits we'd need to know the actual DBMS. And how to join them is depended on what result you want.

Comment: what do you mean by actual DMBS. I am using TSQL on SSMS.

Comment: So the DBMS is likely to be SQL Server... I added the tag for you.

Comment: I am unable to post any type of data sample due to DNA portion of my contract.  I am asking a general question.

Comment: You don't need to post actual data just mock up data that illustrates the problem would be enough. But somehow my effort in asking and explaining seems futile. Meanwhile I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Can you please answer 1 question, is there a limit to the number of sub-queries that can be used within a WITH Statement?